# Using watch with multi line command

Tags: bash

This bash loop works fine.

```
for x in a b c 
do
  echo "$x has `ls file_${x} 2>/dev/null | wc -l`"
done
```

Request to embed it into a 'watch' repeat loop.

Try#1 fails

```
watch --interval 30  for x in a b c 
do
  echo "$x has `ls file_${x} 2>/dev/null | wc -l`"
done
```

Try#2 fails

```
watch --interval 30 ( for x in a b c 
do
  echo "$x has `ls file_${x} 2>/dev/null | wc -l`"
done )
```

Comment: Although you [shouldn't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), try wrapping it in single quotes: `watch … 'for x in … done'`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the command in quotes. Otherwise, the command ends as soon as you type the newline. Also, the variables will be expanded in the original shell, not when the `for` loop iterates.

```
watch --interval 30  'for x in a b c 
do
  echo "$x has $(ls file_${x} 2>/dev/null | wc -l)"
done'
```

I also recommend you stop using the archaic backticks for command substitution, use modern `$(command)`.